# Conditions base insert from one datatable to other in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables in my C# code, `dtProducts` filled from a SQL Server table, and `dtProductdetails` filled from MS Access.

`dtProduct` has columns `code` and `name`, and `dtProductdetails` has columns `id`, `code`, `localname`, `price`.

I need to replace `localname` in `dtProductdetails` and replace with `name` from `dtProducts` code has uniqueness in both data tables.

And then will update `dtproductdetails` to third table in SQL Server.

First: how Do I do this? Second: I have more than 100K records to operate with, can anyone please suggest best way of doing this with respect to performance.

Comment: what DB? MSSQL? is `code` unique field for `join` product and details? use indexes

Comment: MSSQL as db and code is unique in both, how to use indexes

Comment: I would start with not doing it in C#

Comment: @Paparazzi then where?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the following query, which should perform what you are looking for database-side:

```
UPDATE dtProductdetails
SET PD.localname = P.name
FROM dtProductdetails PD
JOIN dtProducts P ON PD.code = P.code
```

You can use the following `C#` code for performing the update:

```
dtProductdetails.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Join
    (
        dtProducts.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(),
        r1 => new { p1 = r1["code"], p2 = r1["code"] },
        r2 => new { p1 = r2["code"], p2 = r2["code"] },
        (r1, r2) => new { r1, r2 }
    )
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(o => o.r1.SetField("localname", o.r2["name"]));
```

Alternatively:

```
var query = from r1 in dtProductdetails.AsEnumerable()
            join r2 in dtProducts.AsEnumerable()
            on r1.Field<Int32>("code") equals r2.Field<Int32>("code")
            select new { r1, r2 };

foreach (var x in query)
    x.r1.SetField("localname", x.r2.Field<String>("name"));
```

Make sure that the `code` field, for both table, is set as a key index.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to create indexes on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes)
Also you can use `UPDATE JOIN` plain `SQL` to update records

```
UPDATE dtProductdetails
SET localname = name
FROM dtProductdetails
JOIN dtProducts
     ON dtProductdetails.code = dtProducts.code
```

Index can be created in this way, this will improve your performance for `join`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UI_dtProductdetails_Code   
   ON dtProductdetails (code);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UI_dtProducts_Code   
   ON dtProducts (code);
```